# Generate _id for array of objects in mongoodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want a MongoDB code for the following problem I am facing.
I want to insert a document in the collection name 'option'.
The document should be like,

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7637f78d480ca9a6b3590d"),
    "createdBy" : "support",
    "optionName" : "Nationality",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-09T11:31:03.442Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "option" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d7637f78d480ca9a6b3590e"),
            "optionValue" : "Malaysian",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive" : true
        }, 
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5d7637f78d480ca9a6b3590f"),
            "optionValue" : "Singaporean",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I used the following code to insert,

```
db.getCollection('option').insert({
    "createdBy" : "support",
    "optionName" : "Nationality",
    "createdDate" :new Date(),
    "isActive" : true,
      "option":[
{
            "optionValue":"Malaysian",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive" : true
},{
            "optionValue":"Singaporean",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive":true
}]
    })
```

But I got,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d763a078d480ca9a6b35910"),
    "createdBy" : "support",
    "optionName" : "Nationality",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-09T11:39:51.487Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "option" : [ 
        {
            "optionValue" : "Malaysian",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive" : true
        }, 
        {
            "optionValue" : "Singaporean",
            "createdBy" : "support",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
            "isActive" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want _id in the array of objects by automatically. Can anyone help to figure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `ObjectId()` as a value for your `option` `_id`.

ObjectId() will crate new id like Mongo documentId.

For example in your case you can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('blah').insert([
    {
        "createdBy" : "support",
        "optionName" : "Nationality",
        "createdDate" :new Date(),
        "isActive" : true,
        "option":[
            {
                "_id": ObjectId(),
                "optionValue":"Malaysian",
                "createdBy" : "support",
                "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
                "isActive" : true
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId(),
                "optionValue":"Singaporean",
                "createdBy" : "support",
                "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-06-30T08:19:09.709Z"),
                "isActive":true
            }
        ]
    }
])
```

Comment: No problem I enjoyed helping you @Tina

Comment: Is it possible to refer that id's in another schema and how to populate those id's?  Can you please help me.